# Ubuntu 16.04.3 installed but not starting; TPM error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, tpm

I have a HP Compaq Elite 8300 SFF (bought refurbished with Win10 Pro prepared). It has an SSD and started installation of Win10 after switching on. Worked fine.

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 from USB stick in a separate partition. It also worked well. Even a restart worked; then I installed updates and some standard stuff, created users etc. Nothing really special.

After reboot I got these two errors:

```
TPM error (7) occured attempting to read a pcr value  
*ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder
```

and was welcomed in emergency mode.
I found several hints regarding these two error lines but none of it helped yet.

I wanted to disable TPM but the HP BIOS has no TPM option at all. BIOS has Version 2.15.1229.

Is there anything I can do to get back my Ubuntu? To me it looks like a UEFI / SecureBoot thing or something like that; but I do not understand why I could install Ubuntu and reboot it once (or twice) and cannot run it anymore?!

Any help very appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance

Arwed